# How to create a channel path with BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to create a channel path for each user id based on the sequence in which the user have visited the website and I want to sum the total transactions per path. The idea is to do this with Bigquery.

I have the following input table:

```
           user id - date       - hits.time - channelgrouping - transaction
           xxxxxxx - 2017-01-01 - 23234     - google cpc      - 1          
           xxxxxxx - 2017-01-02 - 23234     - email           - 0
```

The outpout table I want is:

```
           user id - channelgrouping path - transaction
           xxxxxxx - google cpc > email   - 1
```

Can anyone help me to get started by providing the code to create the path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see below as an example and direction

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, '2017-01-01' AS DATE, 'google cpc' AS channelgrouping, 1 AS transaction UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-01-02', 'email', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-01-01', 'abc', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-01-02', 'xyz', 3 
)
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  STRING_AGG(channelgrouping, ' > ') AS channelgrouping_path,
  SUM(transaction) AS transaction
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
-- ORDER BY USER_ID
```

output is as below

```sql
user_id channelgrouping_path    transaction  
1       google cpc > email      1    
2       abc > xyz               5
```

> example based on your exact query :

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitorId
  ,STRING_AGG(channelgrouping, ' > ') AS channelgrouping_path
  ,SUM(transactions) AS transaction
FROM (
  SELECT 
    date
    ,visitorId
    ,channelgrouping
    ,SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY
    date
    ,visitorId
    ,channelGrouping
)
GROUP BY visitorId
```

make sure you replace `project.dataset.table` with respective yours

> I will have to order the dataset by date and hits.time which is quite heavy to execute.

See an example of how control order withing aggregated string

```sql
STRING_AGG(channelgrouping, ' > ' ORDER BY date) AS channelgrouping_path
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail this is very helpfull! But unfortunately the string_agg() funtion is not supported by Bigquery. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @gvkleef - have you even tried to run exactly as it is in my answer?! please note it is for BigQuery Standard SQL! please try again and let m eknow if still issue  - so we will try to address ti

Comment: Sorry I directly tried it on my own data and my own version of the script. When I use your script everything works fine. When I use mine I get the following error: 4.12 - 4.38: Unrecognized function string_agg

Comment: @gvkleef - do you make sure you are in standard sql mode? - take a look at first line in my example  - you should add same to yours

Comment: @gvkleef - Oh boy ...  :o) see addition in my answer - hope you will make it work now!

Comment: Thanks now it's working perfect. I didn't know that the command #standardSQL could be used, nice :)

For my understanding: now the sequence of the path is based on the number of the row within the dataset? In other words: the first channel SQL comes by is the first channel in the path? In that case I will have to order the dataset by date and hits.time which is quite heavy to execute.

Comment: @gvkleef - will update answer shortly to address ordering you rised in last comment!

Comment: @gvkleef - see update in answer. if not yet  - please vote for answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering all my questions! I've accepted the answer. How do I vote for the answer?

Comment: I have an other question on this subject and created a new 'question topic' for it, because I thought this thread would get messy. Maybe you can take a look if you have the time for it. Would appreciate it very much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408147/how-to-create-a-channelpath-in-bigquery-based-on-events