# How to create a channelpath in BigQuery based on events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to create channelpaths in Bigquery on a user level. I want the path to end when a transaction occurs. The next visit will then start a new path. Currently I have one path per user summing all the transactions. See the provided code below. I've also included the current OUTPUT TABLE and the desired OUTPUT TABLE.

My idea would be to create a new column that is counting the transactions. This value would start at 0 and need to be incremented by 1 AFTER a transaction occured. Then I would merge this value with the user_id value and group the aggregated strings on that variable. But I dont know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Guido

```
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id,'1a' as visit_id, '2017-01-01 14:10:12' AS DATETIME, 
'google cpc' AS channelgrouping, 0 AS transaction , 1 as visit UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1b', '2017-01-01 20:10:12', 'email', 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1c','2017-01-03 08:10:12', 'direct', 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1d','2017-01-04 13:10:14', 'organic', 1, 1
)
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  STRING_AGG(channelgrouping, ' > ' ORDER BY DATETIME) AS channelgrouping_path,
  SUM(transaction) AS transaction,
  SUM(visit) AS visits
 FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
```

OUTPUT TABLE

```
user_id|channgelgrouping_path                |Transactions|Visits
1      |google cpc > email > direct > organic| 2          | 4
```

DESIRED OUTPUT TABLE

```
user_id|channgelgrouping_path                |Transactions|Visits
1      |google cpc > email                   | 1          | 2
1      |direct > organic                     | 1          | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id,'1a' AS visit_id, '2017-01-01 14:10:12' AS DATETIME, 
'google cpc' AS channelgrouping, 0 AS transaction , 1 AS visit UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1b', '2017-01-01 20:10:12', 'email', 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1c','2017-01-03 08:10:12', 'direct', 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1d','2017-01-04 13:10:14', 'organic', 1, 1
)
SELECT
  user_id, 
  STRING_AGG(channelgrouping, ' > ' ORDER BY DATETIME) AS channelgrouping_path,
  SUM(transaction) AS transaction,
  SUM(visit) AS visits
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(transaction) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY datetime 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS grp
  FROM yourTable
)
GROUP BY user_id, IFNULL(grp, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks again Mikhail this is exactly what I was looking for. 

Can you maybe explain the ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING function? And why did you add IFNULL(grp, 0) to the GROUP BY?

Comment: check Analytic Functions https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions and specifically Window Frame Clause. `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` says  - do SUM for all rows before current rows.  `IFNULL(grp, 0)` needed because for very first row - there is no any preceding rows thus sum will be null that we need to "translate" into 0

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can calculate the difference between the visit timestamp of first and last channel in the path? I thought I first ask you before creating a new question.